# Convert a JSX.Element to an HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I want to use this library for my react js project https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image.

In my case I want to use a var that contain a simple div and export It as an Image, but there's a problem: my var (node) is a `JSX.Element` and the "toPng" method of the library accept as a parameter an `HTMLElement`.

[image]

[image]

I know that the doc of the library suggests to use methods like this to get an HTMLElement: `var node = document.getElementById('my-node')` but in my case I can't do something like this because my node isn't in the document.

So there's a way to convert a JSX.Element to an HTMLElement? Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: How about `'react-dom/server'`'s `renderToString`?

Comment: @k-wasilewski Thanks for the advice, I just tried what you suggested to me but `renderToString`returns a string and toPng method needs an HTMLElement

Comment: So I guess you need an ordinary `React.render` and then `React.findDOMNode` to get your element.

Comment: Trying to do exact same thing, I saw you didn't accept 1 answer you have got. Did you found better solution? If so could you post it here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To do that, use [`renderToStaticMarkup`](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server/renderToStaticMarkup) from the `react-dom/server` library.

```js
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from "react-dom/server"

const output = document.createElement('p')
const staticElement = renderToStaticMarkup(reactElement)
output.innerHTML = staticElement
```

Comment: just to mention that if you have something like `<p onclick="` that won't work with this, as is suggested in the name, in that case you might need to use `p.onclick=function(){}`

Comment: The documentation states, "renderToStaticMarkup works in the browser, but using it in the client code is not recommended." What makes this okay?

Answer (score 0):

Question might be old, but while looking for a solution for this I found an elegant way to render a hidden element as an image.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div
                id="image-template"
                className="d-none"
                style={{
                    width: "200px",
                    height: "200px",
                    display: "flex",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    color: "white",
                    fontSize: "10px",
                    textAlign: "center",
                    backgroundColor: "green",
                }}
            >
                <span style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{"Hey, an image rendered but not visible!"}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

With the class `d-none` (from bootstrap) the element is hidden to the user, so it does not matter where you place it. `d-none` in bootstrap is basically `display: none !important;`.

Now add a function to create an image:

```
async createImage() {
    const template = document.getElementById("image-template").cloneNode(true);
    template.classList.remove("d-none");

    const base64Image = await htmlToImage.toPng(template, {
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
    });
    // Do whatever you want to do with your image
}
```

The element is cloned and the `d-none`/`display: none` removed to be able to render it with `htmlToImage`. The result is the base64 data you can use whereever you want.